# c# -> Kafka over TLS: "The message received was unexpected or badly formatted"

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to connect to Kafka having TLS enabled from C# client and getting exception "*The message received was unexpected or badly formatted*" during call to `sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient()`. Unfortunately none of posts in internet helped me so far to resolve the issue. Any idea what can be wrong?

Here is minimal sample C# code I used to initiate connection

```
namespace test_tls {
    class Program {
        static string clientCertificateFile = "C:\\Temp\\<CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_FILE>.crt";
        static X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(clientCertificateFile);

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var clientCertificateCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(new X509Certificate2[] { clientCertificate });

            try {
                using( var client = new TcpClient("<IP_ADDRESS>", 9093) )
                using( var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, CertificateValidator) ) {

                    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("<TARGET_HOST_NAME_AS_IN_THE_CERTIFICATE>",
                        clientCertificateCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);

                    //send/receive from the sslStream
                }
            }
            catch( Exception e ) {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("\n\n\nPress ENTER to exit");
                Console.In.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        static bool CertificateValidator(Object sender, 
                X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
            if( sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None ) {
                return true;
            }
            if( sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors ) {
                //we don't have a proper certificate tree
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also get this if you have a protocol mismatch, like if the server expects TLS 1.3 but the client doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2):

And after some digging it appears that error message is absolutelly misleading and the root cause of the problem is - 'private key of client certificate' was missing during connection process.

X509Certificate2 should either be loaded using this way

```
string clientCertificateFile = "C:\\path\\to\\my.certificate.pfx";
X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(clientCertificateFile, "<password>");
```

or from local certificate store (and it should be imported there with private key)

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2 cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "<Certificate 'Issued To' name>", false)[0];
```

Note: if you have you certificate and private key in separate files, this command can be used to merge them into PFX file

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my.cer -inkey my.key -out mycert.pfx
```